# Keras Metrics unexpected behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a speech denoising problem using DNN. I am calculating my SNR ratio by the function below.

```
def calculate_snr(clean_signal, recovered_signal):

    clean_power = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(clean_signal))

    noise_power = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(clean_signal - recovered_signal))

    snr_db = 10 * tf.math.log(clean_power / noise_power) / tf.math.log(10.0)

    return snr_db
```

I am using keras api to create a model like this

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),metrics=[calculate_snr])

sound_denoising_history = model.fit(x = X_abs.T, y = S_abs.T,epochs=200,batch_size = 100,validation_data=(X_test_01_abs.T,S_test_01_abs.T))

calculate_snr (X_test_01_abs.T,model.predict(X_test_01_abs.T) : 10.9
While model fit: -4.4 to -3
```

When I train it, I see that my SNR metric for validation is -7 and oscillates in that range. Whereas if I predict on xval input and then use that with the above function, It gives me 8.2. It is the same identical function and I have checked dimensions multiple times. I am not sure what is happening?

Edit: I know I am missing a step of processing for snr calculation for a signal but even if the metric was standalone usage, it should yield the almost the same ballpark on train end and then inference followed by calculation

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you perform the prediction?

Comment: Yes. Edited with model inference